Azure Functions concurrency behaviour: maxConcurrentRequests
I am currently trying to "tune" the concurrency parameters for the function app (python 3.10 runtime) we have at work, though I am confused as to how to interpret the behaviour that I am seeing.
The app is running on an App Service Plan (dedicated plan) with P1mv3 compute, which means 2 vCPUs on a single instance. The app to my knowledge from testing and reading the code is CPU bound. For this reason I have set the FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT app setting to 2 (the number of vCPU cores available).
Now my thought was to set the maxConcurrentRequests parameter in host.json to 2 as well such that each request that goes in gets full compute available. From my testing, I see the following results:



maxConcurrentRequests
10 Requests response time (s)




1
25


2
20


10
18



I would assume that 10 reduces overhead of fetching requests but would like to know a bit more about what happens under the hood. When it takes 10 requests, does each of my processes take a request (so 2 at a time), then process these sequentially and only returning responses after finishing the entire batch?
Thanks in advance! If anyone has some advice or workflow to find out good settings for new cases, let me know! I am very curious since I felt like I was stumbling through this task.

Please share your config file.
